# Inter-assembly aggregation in C#

Tags: c#, persistence

I have a .NET solution with 4 library projects resulting in 4 assemblies.

There are classes in these assemblies that generate some partial information in a linear workflow. 
By information=generated I mean some business logic information inclusive of timestamp, # of records etc.
The final table into which this information has to be inserted contains 16 columns...each of these assemblies have loggable information for just 4 columns.
My objective is to aggregate all this information and log it to the database in a single DB call...instead of doing it 4 times.

To be more clear, a class in namespace A which (namespace/assembly A imports/uses B and C)...  instantiatesa class inside B and C respectively .

I do not have access to information generated in methods inside  B and C classes in the class in namespaceA. But I want to aggregate all of the information and push it to the database in a single insert.

How should I approach this problem?
I want to persist the data across all these different assemblies and log the data to the databse in a single call.How can I persist the data?

Comment: You have (badly) described how you want to implement this, but you haven't said what you're trying to accomplish - why do you want to do this? Besides, neither methods nor assemblies are instantiated.

Comment: @John Saunders point taken;question edited...hope this establishes clarity...

Comment: Not by much. What is this "information generated"?

Comment: @John Saunders question re-edited; information is just loggable business-logic...but only partially available... in each of the individual classes in different assemblies.

Comment: I *think* the assemblies are a red herring.

Comment: It reaslly sounds like you haven't thought it through. What do you mean "loggable logic"?

Comment: @John Saunders The thing is these are pre-existing legacy assemblies; the assemblies are nested through calls...each of the assembly does its own specific part of cusiness-logic processing. The functionality I am trying to implement is to track some parameters as the logic is processed...and log them to a central repository.

Comment: I was right. You haven't thought it through. You have legacy code that you presumably can't touch. You want it to suddenly start behaving differently, without touching the code. Good Luck.

Comment: @John Saunders I **can** touch the legacy code...and expose the data to the new assembly...but the issue as I mentioned is to first collect the data from disparate sources...and then log them.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to log each piece of data as a chunk of XML, or binary, or plain text, or do you need a set of rows in a database, with separate columns, etc.

Comment: @John Saunders The final step is the push to the DB...the intermediate step(s) can be XML.

Comment: Or, why not send XML to the database? SQL Server 2005 and up allow XML to be stored, indexed, and queried.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert data produced by classes A, B, and C all at once, then *something* needs to be able to access all of that data at the insertion point.

If, as you say, B and C aren't available to A, have you considered a separate class (in its own assembly, for example) that is concerned only with persistence?

Such a class could reference A, B, and C, pull the data from each (assuming that they expose their data, somehow... if not, I've no idea how you'd accomplish what you seek), aggregate that data and insert it.

This way, A, B, and C remain ignorant of each other, and of the class that persists their data.

Comment: This would work over my visitor/collecting parameter if you didn't want to make any changes to existing code...

Comment: The separate class in its own assembly pulls the data...has been considered and I have the *exact* problem of how to expose this data from source assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, then it doesn't make sense.

If you have individual classes generating data that should be logged, then these individual classes should log the data. No other class should have to know which data the individual classes find interesting.

Let your logging framework deal with bundling the logging information into an appropriate number of database calls. That's an implementation detail of the logging framework.

Comment: I agree...but the problem I am facing there is regarding that implementation. assume my logging framework has the DTO...representing the final aggregate. Each individual class...populates the DTO...but how can that information be persisted here?  A.PopulateDTO(p1,p2,p3) ... followed by say C.PopulateDTO(p5,p6) ... how will p1,p2,p3 be persisted?

Comment: You don't use a DTO, and you don't aggregate. Use XML or name/value pairs or something else generic.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can interpret the question, I suspect you might benefit from an aggregator class (a [Collecting Parameter](http://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/accumulationToCollection.html) or even a more complicated [Visitor](http://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/accumulationToVisitor.html)) that visits each information generating class, compiles data, and can then eventually be asked to publish the compiled data somewhere else.